# What does assigning units as decoys do?

Tags: star-wars-rebellion

When creating a covert ops mission it's possible to assign units to the mission, but also units as decoy. What's the effect units have as decoy, and when is it best to assign a decoy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this website](http://www.swrebellion.com/faq-9-Characters+and+Special+Forces.html):

> Decoys are used to draw attention from the characters performing the real mission. To have someone be a decoy, they must be able to do the real mission on their own and you generally want to use someone who has a good espionage value.

It seems you want to assign units with high espionage levels to be decoys.  From the sound of it, they distract other troops from the people performing the actual mission, making it easier on them.